# Using the monotone class argument to prove martingale property

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, monotone-class-theorem

I'm having trouble with the following statement:

For the stochastic process $(M_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ to be a martingale it suffices to show that
\begin{equation}\label{green}
\mathbb{E}[(M_t-M_s)\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_i(M_{s_i})]=0,
\end{equation}
using a standard monotone class argument, where $f_i$ are continuous, bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{s_1,...,s_n\}\subseteq [0,s]$.

I've already shown that the process is adapted and integrable (it is bounded), but I fail to show the martingale property from the equation above.

Comment: It would help to recall the definition of $M^{*}$ for those who don't know (or can't remember).

Comment: I'm sorry, the statement was made for the limit of a sequence of stochastic processes, but this doesn't matter here. The $M^*$ is just the limit of $M^N$. Again it's not important, therefore I'm editing it.

Comment: What is the filtration?  Is it $\mathcal{F}_{t} = \sigma(M_{s} \, \mid \, s \in [0,t])$?